# Launcher is not executable

Tags: java, linux, install4j

I've created a DEB file with Install4J (with Linux and also with MacOS). The launcher file is an external file which is executable after I've built the project. Now, if I install the DEB file in a Linux environment the launcher file is not executable anymore. I've tried to set it hard with "Set the UNIX access mode" action, but this didn't help. How can I achieve that the file is executable? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a [postinst (or preinst)](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html) script to your deb; make it executable in the script.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried to set it hard with "Set the UNIX access mode" action, but this didn't help.

For a DEB file, no actions are executed, so the "Set the UNIX access mode of files and directories" action is not relevant in this context.

The file mode for launchers is determined by the setting in the launcher wizard, on the "Executable info->Unix options" step.